# add passenger module to nginx without sources

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

I have a ubuntu 10.04 server and i've installed nginx from repositories with:

```
apt-get install nginx
```

i have all my sites running and i want to install redmine but i'm having problems with passenger.
I have installed passenger but i can add it to nginx because i dont have the sources so i can't use:

```
passenger-install-nginx-module
```

Would this break my current nginx installation?
Is there any way of install passenger module?
can i have 2 nginx servers running on the same machine, different port?I could install redmine in a nginx on another port.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Passenger Standalone (which is based on nginx) and set this to listen on different port or IP than main nginx.

In your case simply run:

```
sudo passenger start
```

in redmine root directory. If everything is ok you should see redmine under

```
http://YOUR_SERVER_IP:3000
```

More info: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html

Answer (score 0):

Either install it from [Brightbox](http://blog.brightbox.co.uk/posts/nginx-passenger-3-ubuntu-packages) repository or you must recompile the Nginx. Sure, you also can run 2 Nginx instances with different port if you really want.

---

> I can't believe i have to recompile nginx to add a module!

AFAIK, Nginx doesn't support the loadable modules mechanism.

Comment: i know about brightbox but it means a new installation too.I can't believe i have to recompile nginx to add a module!! I'm talking about a production site so i don't want to recompile or reinstall and loose my webs or run into trouble.I was thinking in install a second nginx instance and migrate all webs there and then remove the first one, but installing redmine is not so important for doing all this work.

Comment: @Oterox: Nginx requires does not support dynamic loading of modules for performance reasons, recompiling nginx does not require any downtime of your webserver, though.